# Twilio Whitepages API in python not returning data

Tags: python, twilio

I'm trying to use the whitepages pro lookup API and it's coming up short somehow. This is the code I've got:

```
    client = Client(twilio_account_sid, twilio_auth_token)
    phone_number1= client.lookups.phone_numbers("+13107042708").fetch(
            add_ons='whitepages_pro_caller_id')
    print(phone_number1.carrier)
    phone_number2 = client.lookups.phone_numbers("+17604459760").fetch(
            add_ons='whitepages_pro_caller_id')
    print(phone_number2.carrier)
```

It's just turning up blank data on my flask backend, None

```
[2019-04-16 22:25:41 +0000] [29715] [DEBUG] GET /api/confcall
2019-04-16 22:25:41.547697
[2019-04-16 22:25:41 +0000] [29715] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
None
None
```

Any tips? Thanks in advance, I must be doing something very obviously wrong as I'm basing this copied off of this documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/api?code-sample=code-get-additional-caller-information-with-lookup-and-whitepages-pro-caller-id-add-on&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x

Comment: If you try with cURL or Postman, what's the response?

Comment: Yeah get this twilio support reached back and they told us they confirmed this doesn't work with their provided APIs after testing but apparently it works just fine for curl

Comment: This was pretty much verbatim from the provided example... so yeah big whoops on their end haha I wonder how much this broke stuff for other people

Comment: Time to integrate libcurl now basically their API is goof trooped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has been updated to fix the issue you raised, thank you for pointing that out.

Please visit:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/api?code-sample=code-get-additional-caller-information-with-lookup-and-whitepages-pro-caller-id-add-on&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x

Alan

Comment: Cheers thanks a bunch Alan, this is exactly what I needed